# How to fix json loading error (json.load not working)

Tags: python, json

So I was coding from NeuralNine's tutorial, did all the same,his code worked, mine didn't
the error is in this line >> intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
for all I know this should work
How do I fix that?

```
import json
import pickle
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD

lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer

intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())

words = []
classes = []
documents = []
ignore_letters = ['!', '?', ',', '.']

for intent in intents['intents']:
    for pattern in intent['patterns']:
        word_list = nltk.word_tokenize(pattern)
        words.append(word_list)
        documents.append((word_list, intent['tag']))
        if intent['tag'] not in classes:
            classes.append(intent['tag'])
```

and the error was:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 198, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.2\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/****/PycharmProjects/AIyoutube/train.py", line 13, in <module>
    intents = json.loads(open('intents.json').read())
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 1411: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: What is in your json file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
open('intents.json', 'r', encoding='UTF-8')
```

or another codec